# Две связи один-ко-многим в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть две таблицы:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('number');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_ht');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_at');
            $table->foreign('id_ht')
                ->references('id')->on('players')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('id_at')
                ->references('id')->on('players')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('players', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('number');;
        $table->string('full_name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Не понимаю как должны выглядеть модель и контроллер чтобы связать эти две таблицы связью один ко многим. Мне нужно на странице игрока получить матчи в которых он играл, и соответственно на странице матча игроков которые в нем играли.

Comment: Очевидно, что матч-игрок это связь __многие ко многим__. Так как в матче участвует много игроков, и игрок участвует во многих матчах.

Comment: Не совсем так, в матче участвует два игрока (теннис). id_ht - первый игрок, id_at - второй

Comment: 2,3,4 или сколько угодно игроков кроме __одного__ - это связь многие ко многим. Поэтому лучше не изобретать костыли, а использовать многие-ко-многим.

Comment: Понял, буду в эту сторону копать